# Setup project: where .net framework 4.0 is hidden?

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

I build MSI file with MSVS 2010 setup project and wonder why does it requires .net framework 4.0 to be installed.

I double checked that every module in setup dependencies relies on .NF 3.5 SP1, and .NF 3.5 SP1 is in prerequisites list. But somehow Visual Studio Project File contains the following part:

..

```
SccProvider 
  Deployable 
    ExternalPersistence
       LaunchCondition 
         ... NETFramework, Version=v4.0, Profile=Client
```

I can't figure out what on Earth adds this reference into project file.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with setup projects but have you configured it so that the MSI itself needs .Net 4? eg in the project settings for the setup project itself.

Comment: Sorry, but property page for this type of project doesn't provide any .NF version option in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer to myself.

You should click with right mouse button on the the setup project in solution explorer, go to "view", then to "launch conditions" and change .net framework version to appropriate one.